# How to match redirect with subdomain in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, routes

I have the following working route in my project:

```
  match 'investidor/*path' => redirect('investidores/entrar'), via: :get
```

And I need to change it to redirect to a **different subdomain** as well, like this in development:

```
  match 'investidor/*path' => redirect('http://investidor.lvh.me:3000/investidores/entrar'), via: :get
```

This code works, but I need to adapt it to work with multiple environments and multiple resources, so I don't want to use `if Rails.env.ENVIRONMENT?` to do that, unless there's no other way around it.
So I tried things like:

```
  match 'investidor/*path' => redirect('investidores/entrar'), via: :get, subdomain: 'investidor'
  # AND
  match 'investidor/*path' => redirect('investidores/entrar'), via: :get, constraints: { subdomain: 'investidor' }
```

But both of those redirects ignore the subdomain parameter. Is there any way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: I know you didn't want to use a conditional but its not as ugly as you may think...   subdomain = Rails.env.development? ? '/path' : '/'

Comment: I know, but I just wanted to make sure there's no other way to do that since I also have a staging environment, so I won't be able to use an inline if

Answer (score 1):

I would use config/environments/*.rb to set a subdomain value and reference that in routes.

eg:

```
    # config/environments/development.rb:
Rails.application.configure do
  SUBDOMAIN="dev_domain"
...


# config/environments/production.rb:
Rails.application.configure do
  SUBDOMAIN="prod_domain"
...

# config/routes.rb:
'investidor/*path' => redirect("http://#{SUBDOMAIN}/investidores/entrar"), via: :get
```

Comment: I'll probably end up using that if there's no other way around it, but I would still need to create a constant for each subdomain (or resources in my case)

Comment: If you only have a few resources to map, that's what I would do. If you have a dozen and they don't change to often, a yml file might be more appropriate (think `domains.yml` formatted similar to `database.yml`). If you have a lot of resources, or they change frequently, I'd move it into a table with an admin interface.